# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python

Tengo un código de tarea de Python que no sé cómo realizarlo.
El código tiene que tomar los números de unas notas de un estudiantes, eliminar el mínimo, promediarlos y redondear el resultado a 2 decimales.
Ahí les dejo el código:

```
def nota_quices(codigo, nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4, nota5):
  nota = [nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4, nota5]
  min_nota = min(nota)
  sum(((nota - min_nota)/4)/20)
  return nota_quices
round(2)

print(nota_quices('AA0010276',40, 50, 39, 76, 96))
```

Pero al ejecutar el código me sale el siguiente error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

el cual no sé solucionar ya que soy nuevo en este lenguaje.

Comment: no puedes operar una lista con un número `3 - [10, 5, 1, 6]`

Comment: lo únicos que necesitas hacer `notas.remove(min_nota)` y luego haces `prom = sum(notas)/len(notas)` y listo

Comment: Christian ese sistema ya lo intente y tambien me da error :/

Comment: Que tanto conocimiento tienes sobre python?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tienes una función que recibe una cantidad variable de valores, lo normal es "agruparlos" en una lista anteponiendo el simbolo "*" delante del nombre que recibirán.

```
def nota_quices(codigo, *nota):
```

Asi tu código queda general, pudiendo recibir cualquier cantidad de notas, la que quedaran almacenadas como una lista en `notas`.

Como ahora tienes un número variable de notas, la cantidad la obtienes con `len(notas) - 1`. `len()` te da el número de elementos en la lista y le quitas uno para descontar el mínimo.

Fijate que la función `sum()` se aplica solo a la lista.

```
  min_nota = min(nota)
  resultado = (sum(nota) - min_nota)/(len(nota) - 1)
```

**Demo**

```
def nota_quices(codigo, *nota):
  min_nota = min(nota)
  resultado = (sum(nota) - min_nota)/(len(nota) - 1)
  return round(resultado, 2)


print(nota_quices('AA0010276',40, 50, 39, 76, 9))
```

produce

```
51.25

Process finished with exit code 0
```